# Handle Excel formatted numbers

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading a CSV file that was generated by another system and they have some columns that number values are formatted for something like "3.6417E+11".

This CSV is hosted in a remote SFTP and downloaded to my server.

I'm reading the context of this CSV and parse it using Pandas but I didn't figure out how to convert those values ("3.6417E+11") to a legible string like "364167341173".

Is possible to parse it on pandas (or python)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do:

```py
import numpy as np 
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
```

For details check it out: http://pythonquirks.blogspot.com/2009/10/controlling-printing-in-numpy.html